# On the number of fixed points of the differential equation $x' = x^3 +ax - b$ depending on $(a,b)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems

equation:
$x' = x^3 +ax - b$

the task is to show that in plane (a,b) there is curve C
which divide the plane into 2 parts A and B
where values from A will give 1 Fixed point for the given equation
and in B there will be 3 Fixed points for the given equation.

now im having some problem in investigating this problem and i was wondering if any of you could give me some hint on how to do so.
what i've done so far:
Fixed point means $x' = 0$ so we have the next equation
$x^3 = -ax + b$ so we can see geometrically that for $a>0$
we have only 1 intersection point which means only 1 fixed point for the equation
so we covered half of the (a,b) plane by now ($a > 0$).
now when $a < 0 $ there could be couple of cases which im having hard time to find.
any idea would be much appreciated.

**Edit:** Thanks to MrYouMath, for any one who wonders 
you can see the intersections between 2 points right [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nrpxfuzbta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $x'=0=x^3+ax-b$ Is a cubic equation, which can have 1 or 3 real solutions. You can even calculate them with [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method).

In order to show that there is always at least one real solution look at $p(x)=x^3+ax-b$ for $|x|\to \infty$ and use the intermediate value theorem.

If $p(x)$ has at least one real solution $x_1$ then we can rewrite the polynomial as $p(x)=(x-x_1)(x^2+\alpha x+ \beta)$. The quadratic part has again real coefficients and this can have no real solution, or two real solution.

**Edit**: If you want to find the curve you can use the [cubic discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Degree_3) $\Delta = -4a^3-27b^2$. If the cubic discriminant is zero then we have a double zero, which is the case that is separating the one + two real solutions case to the one real + 2 complex conjugate solutions. So the curve of separation is given by the implicit curve $F(a,b)=4a^3+27b^2=0$.

Comment: the real problem is that i cant isolate $\alpha$ and $\beta$ from the quadratic part ($\alpha = r_2 , \beta = r_3$)
$(x - r_1)(x^2 + r_2x + r_3) = x^3 + ax - b$  
im getting that  
$r_3 - r_2^2 = a$  and  
$r_3r_2 = b$   
now from the quadratic equation we know that if
$r_2^2 - 4r_3 < 0$ it leads to no real solution
so what im trying to do is to isolate $r_2$ and $r_3$ as functions of $a$ and $b$
and find this curve where we'll have 3 real solutions and 1 real solution

Comment: its obvious that it has 1 or 3 real solutions but i need to find the curve C which divide the plane for these 2 parts 
where 1 part has 1 real solution while the other has 3

Comment: thats excatly what i wrote 2 comments above, 
i need to represent this curve on plane (a,b) for that
i need to isolate $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as functions of $a$ and $b$

Comment: I have added an edit to my answer.

Comment: good to learn new things!! never had to deal with cubic polynoms so i didnt know that.
thank you very much, looks perfect!